# Is hashCode() considered as a hash function?

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, hashcode

Im currently having a programming task on my university about hash tables, yet, the task specifically said that we cannot use any Hash functions from Java or any ADT libraries, if so, is hashCode() considered as a hash Function? I am deeply confused.

Thank you for your help :D

Comment: I am too: a hash table, by definition, needs to use a hash function. Ask your teacher for clarifications.

Comment: Yes. But if you are unsure then just ask your professor. What specifically is your assignment?

Comment: They probably mean to construct the hash function yourself. IE) implement your own `HashMap`, do not use the built in, and don't use already existing `hashCode` implementations. Ask your professor to clarify.

Comment: @xtratic  well technically its a modified version of finding the substring of a string, yet for every substring length, we would only display the highest occurences (if its equal we would take the first occurence of the substring). eg. abab would print out a|2,ab|2,aba|1,abab|1.  I was planning to use the Rabin-Karps Algorithm for indexing yet we would still need to check on ba,bab..etc pattern, therefore I think its much faster to find all the possible substrings, and put in an array (using hashCode as the index).

Comment: Like Flakes says, I expect they want you to write the hash table and functions for yourself if that's what you're currently learning about. But checking with your professor if you are unsure of the limitations or purpose of the assignment is your best bet.